# SU, SUDO and Upgrade problem

Tags: upgrade, samba, sudo, su

i have a big problem with my Ubuntu PC.

When i try sometigng need sudo or su, nothing is working and the OS Upgrade too, when i write the root password to the su command i have a "autentication error", same in the upgrades and when i try the sudo command to install something i don't have error message and nothing happen.

I was tring to make samba work when all goes wrong.

Some help!?

Thanks!

Edit

1. SSH connection refused and connection closed if i try to login from secondary PC
2. I can't access recovery mode...
3. With the autologin i can access the system, if i logout and try to login again return the autentication error

Comment: No solution found.
I had to reinstall/fix Ubuntu from the installation/live CD

Answer (score 0):

It may be an issue with pam. Can you include the contents of

```
/etc/pam.d/sudo
/etc/pam.d/su
```

As a side note, you may have more luck with this question in a forum. You are probably going to have to post a lot of information specific to your system setup to solve this.

Comment: SUDO
------------------
#%PAM-1.0

auth       required   pam_env.so readenv=1 user_readenv=0
auth       required   pam_env.so readenv=1 envfile=/etc/default/locale user_rea$
@ include common-auth
@ include common-account
@ include common-session-noninteractive
------------------

SU
------------------
auth       sufficient pam_rootok.so
session       required   pam_env.so readenv=1
session       required   pam_env.so readenv=1 envfile=/etc/default/locale
session    optional   pam_mail.so nopen
------------------